# Is there a way we can export gitlab merge request metrics through api of users

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

Using git-lab, in order to verify the users contributions, can we get individuals metrics like:

1. total_number of merge_requests raised
2. total_number of review comments provided for other merge_requests
3. total_number of approvals users done so far for other merge_requests
4. total_number of review_comments received for there own merge_requests